# Android: SQLite Exception?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Im attempting to create a method that runs a query in order to recieve results from my SQLite database. However I am getting an error in Logcat, and the application stops working. How do I solve this?

**The query:**

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + "WHERE COL_SCORE >= " + scoreEntered  ;
```

**Logcat error Log:**

```
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365): Process: com.example.brianapp, PID: 29365
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ">=": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT  * FROM scoresWHERE COL_SCORE >=4
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1121)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:694)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
07-21 16:18:43.527: E/AndroidRuntime(29365):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1375)
```

The full below extended code is for **reference:**

The **full method** is as follows:

```
public List<Score> getSpecificScore(int scoreEntered) {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + "WHERE COL_SCORE >= " + scoreEntered  ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setMeditation(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                score.setMax(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                score.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                score.setDate(cursor.getLong(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return scoreList;
    }
```

The **full databaseHelper Activity** in which the method resides:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    // Database Name
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MeditationDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_MED = "avgmeditation";
    private static final String COL_MAX = "max";
    private static final String COL_SCORE = "score";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "date";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // NOTE: may need to alter the below to take out everything after
        // INTEGER
        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
                + COL_NAME + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + COL_MED + " INTEGER,"
                 + COL_MAX + " INTEGER," + COL_SCORE + " INTEGER," + COL_DATE + " LONG" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);

    }

    /**
     * Method that upgrades the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * All CRUD operations
     */
    // Adding new score details (Name, score, date)
    void addScore(Score score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // ContentValues- holds the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME, score.getName());
        values.put(COL_MED, score.getMeditation());
        values.put(COL_MAX, score.getMax());
        values.put(COL_SCORE, score.getScore());
        values.put(COL_DATE, score.getDate());

        // Inserting Row (i.e. the values that were entered from above
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    /**
     * Method will return a single Name and score
     * 
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    // Getting single score (i.e. not the full db)  
    Score getScore(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] { COL_NAME,
                COL_MED, COL_MAX, COL_SCORE, COL_DATE }, COL_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null,null,null); 
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(cursor.getString(0),Integer.parseInt(cursor
                .getString(1)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)),Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)), cursor.getLong(4));
        // return contact
        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Method will return a list of all the scores
     * 
     * @return
     */
    // Getting All scores
    public List<Score> getAllScores() {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setMeditation(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                score.setMax(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                score.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                score.setDate(cursor.getLong(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return scoreList;
    }



    /**
     * BELOW IS AN ATTEMPT TO DESIGN A METHOD TO ALLOW THE QUERYING OF DATABASE WITHING SEARCH FUNCTION
     */


    public List<Score> getSpecificScore(int scoreEntered) {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + "WHERE COL_SCORE >= " + scoreEntered  ;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setMeditation(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                score.setMax(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
                score.setScore(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(3)));
                score.setDate(cursor.getLong(4));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return scoreList;
    }

}
```

`Invoking` the method, within a different Activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.btnSearch:

            final String entry = scoreEntered.getText().toString();
            // convert from string value to int
            int scoreToSearch = Integer.parseInt(entry); //

            // Creating list of results from the query entered
            List<Score> results = db.getSpecificScore(scoreToSearch);

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given a space before WHERE in "WHERE ....", please see if that works; change:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + "WHERE COL_SCORE >= " + scoreEntered  ;
```

to

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE + " WHERE COL_SCORE >= " + scoreEntered;
```

(Note the space between `"` and `WHERE`)

Comment: Thanks! This has worked. However the TextView in which the results are to be displayed should should over 5 result sets yet it only shows one!